# Windows Pointer Speed 1/11 Left/Right Difference

Tags: mouse, dpi

I found this very old post, where someone cited a long guide about setting mouse sensitivity for CS.
https://www.overclock.net/threads/cs-s-mouse-optimization-guide.173255/

Antigen states that if you lower the pointer setting in windows below 6/11, you would have two different DPI settings for moving left and right. I quote:

"On the other hand, if you reduce the pointer speed setting, even by one notch, you get two different mouse sensitivities and your cursor will move, slowly to the right, and faster to the left."

All of this dates back to the Windows XP Era. I wonder if this is still relevant, and hope someone has an idea what's going on with the settings. Antigen unfortunately didn't explain why lowering the pointer speed results in such weird behaviour.

I tried testing it with https://www.mouse-sensitivity.com/dpianalyzer/, but couldn't observe a difference in going left or right. I tested it with the max DPI setting on my mouse and a fairly low setting. Unfortunately going for high DPI results in a lot of deviation because i dont have a real jig to hold the mouse in parallel to the ruler (cm on paper). With the low setting it also seemed like both directions are equal.
Is this a myth that got debunked eventually or a bug that was fixed in later versions of Windows?

I posted this question on Arqade, someone suggested to post it here. I understand this forum has nothing to do with video games, it's just that the myth about 6/11 sensitivity originated from this scene.